# How do I access a custom tag's attributes in a scriptlet?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am making a custom jsp tag and need to access one of the attributes inside a scriptlet in the tag file.  What do I call to access it.

```
<%@ tag import="com.package.model.Pojo"%>
<%@ attribute name="pojo" type="com.package.model.Pojo"%>

<%
    Pojo pojo = ????
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just took a wild guess and figured it out.
Don't declare it but simply start accessing it. IE:

```
<%@ tag import="com.package.model.Pojo"%>
<%@ attribute name="pojo" type="com.package.model.Pojo"%>

<%
   pojo.getFoo();
%>
```